# ffprobe for metadata - different output on Mac/Linux

Tags: ffmpeg, debian, ffprobe

I am trying to get the metadata from a live .m3u8 stream and I was testing this using Mac and it is working and I can get the data I need, but when putting it onto a Linux (Debian) box, it omits the part that I need, the command is :

```
ffprobe -show_data http://livestreamurl.com
```

Which on Mac, outputs the data I need:

```
Input #0, hls, from 'http://livestreamurl.com':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Program 0
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 130000
  Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 130000
      title           : Crowded House - Locked Out
```

Specifically, it is the `title` part which is "Crowded House - Locked Out"

But when run on Linux, I get this:

```
Input #0, hls,applehttp, from 'http://livestreamurl.com':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Program 0
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 130000
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 130000
```

The Mac version is 4.4 and the Debian version is 3.2.16 (but says it is the latest version available), could this be the issue?

Is there a way for me to get what I need using the Linux box, which is the title section of the metadata on the audio stream?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AAC stream most likely has ID3 tags inserted between frames, which are only parsed starting with ffmpeg 4.x.

You can check the history of `libavformat/aacdec.c`.

The relevant commit is: [Parse ID3 tags between ADTS frames](https://patchwork.ffmpeg.org/project/ffmpeg/patch/20180202023745.68519-1-rshaffer@tunein.com/).

Install or build a more recent version of ffmpeg on Linux.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, the problem was the version of ffmpeg, many thanks.